# Dynamic factor model : forecasting the factors

Tags: statsmodels

The `statsmodels` package offers a `DynamicFactor` object that, when fit, yields a `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor.DynamicFactorResultsWrapper` object. That offers `predict` and `simulate` methods, but both forecast the original time-series, not the underlying latent factor.

I've tried reconstructing the latent factor as an AR process, but have been unsuccessful. The coefficients in both the `.ssm["transition"]` and in the results `.summary()` match, but when simulated as an AR process, don't give me back the factor on the results `.factors["filtered"]`...

How can I generate future values of the latent factors ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is:

```
m = sm.tsa.DynamicFactor(endog, k_factors=1, factor_order=1)
r = m.fit()
f = r.get_forecast(10)
print(f.prediction_results.filtered_state)
```

Note that this is always a numpy array, so if your data has e.g. a Pandas date index, you would need to create the Pandas Series with that index yourself.

Another way to do this is to append `np.nan` values to the end of your dataset, and then use the typical `.factors["filtered"]` accessor. If you append `n` observations with `np.nan`, then the last `n` values of `.factors["filtered"]` will contain the forecasts of the factors.

Comment: Thanks ! The result has a shape of (26, 10) in this case. I was expecting a single factor. Taking the mean of this results in something that doesn't look right. How should I treat this ?

Comment: I tried your second approach also, by adding `np.nan` to the end of the dataset. The forecasted factor monotonically falls to zero, and looks markedly different to previous behaviour. Thanks for any help ! It's much appreciated.